# Segmentation Fault when adding nodes to Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

This method is meant to add a node at the index specified with the value passed into a Linked List, for some reason it gives me a "segmentation fault (core dumped)" error when I run it using sample data. I've narrowed down the cause to be referencing current->next, however I have no idea what to do from here. To my knowledge I am not setting current to a null value and I have checked that the Linked List has valid items. Even when I create a conditional such as:

```
if(current->next) current = current->next
```

the compiler still gives me a segmentation fault.

Code is below:

```
Node* add(Node* head, int index, int valueInput)
{

    Node* newNode;
    newNode->value = valueInput;


    if(index == 0){

        newNode->next = head;
        return newNode;

    }

    int i = 0;
    Node* current = head;

    while(i <= index && current != NULL){

         if(i == (index-1)){

             Node* temp = current->next;
             current->next = newNode;
             newNode->next = temp;

             return head;

         }

        i++;

        current = current->next;


    }

    return NULL;

}

class Node {
    public:
        int value;
        Node* next = NULL;
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at our [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The bug is probably in the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: One easy way to determine where the bug is, is by using `std::cout` to print messages to the screen. Keep moving the following code around to determine where the problem is:  `std::cout << "no error yet" << std::endl`. You will need to include the `<iostream>` header at the top of your cpp file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> Node* newNode;
> ```

You've default initialised a pointer. The value will be indeterminate. The behaviour of reading an indeterminate value is undefined.

> ```
> newNode->value = valueInput;
> ```

You indirect through the indeterminate pointer. The behaviour of the program is undefined.